# Can you slice a numpy array, then set the sliced indices equal to another numpy array of the same length?

Tags: arrays, numpy, slice

Suppose I have a numpy array initialized as

```
numpy_arr_A = np.zeros((A.shape[0], A.shape[1], some_valid_length))
```

Can I slice `numpy_arr_A` so the sliced indices are set to equal a smaller numpy array `numpy_arr_B`?

```
numpy_arr_A[:,:,valid_subset_indices] = numpy_arr_B
```

Comment: It should work if the shape of `numpy_arr_A[:,:,valid_subset_indices]` and `numpy_arr_B` are compatible.

Comment: Got it, I'll be checking my math then. Thanks

Comment: @hpaulj As a follow up question, I am having difficulties while trying to grab just the third dimension from `numpy_arr_b` and set the third dimension (sliced) from `numpy_arr_A` equal to that. I could not find any documentation to help me with that – would you happen to know how to solve this issue?

Comment: That followup does not make sense